# Where does Docker save logs?

Tags: docker, logging, ubuntu-18.04

Docker seems to allow to specify any log driver of choice either through /etc/docker/daemon.json or through options while running a container. Further, it allows specifying driver options too, but is it possible to mention the location where the logs themselves get stored. Or at least can I know where docker is saving the logs even if the location is not customizable.

Reference: For example consider the default driver - [JSON File logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/)

**Environments to consider:** Ubuntu/CentOS/Windows etc... but looking for generic solution.

Comment: If programmatically accessing the logs is important to you, then one of the other logging drivers mentioned in the Docker documentation (any of the sibling pages of your link) would be a more appropriate solution.  On a setup that uses a Docker VM (Docker for Mac, Docker Toolbox) the logs will be inside the VM and won't be directly accessible in any case.

Comment: not acceptable for the -1 as the question is valid and well framed. And above everything, it's a valuable piece of information that's requested. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check docker daemon logs then [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#read-the-logs) is the location where you can find it.

---

To check logs of containers.

In case of default logging driver Json file, you can get the logs using command.

```
docker logs container-id
```

Or get the location of specific container logs using [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' container-id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On wsl2 in Windows it says `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>-json.log` but this folder is empty. Instead you have to mount the docker-desktop-data folder like so: https://superuser.com/a/1782465/682809 and find it in there under "/data/docker/containers/"

Comment: I don't quite understand why it lies about where the files are, there are no symlinks or anything.